# You ARE not TO be here

Tags: sentence

Several times I've heard sentences like *You are not to be here.* whereas I'd expected something with *should*. Or *He is absolutely not to know.*.

What is this form? When should I use it?

Comment: Since all native speakers would be familiar with this usage, I suggest it would be better asked on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Be+to infinitive** is used when you want to express *future events, orders, things that should be/not be done*, etc.

[The link](http://www.grammaring.com/be-to-infinitive) is self-explanatory.

You are not to be here means: You should not be here. You shoud never come here.

He is absolutely not to know means: He should not become aware of what has been discussed/what happened, etc. You should not tell him anything about them.

Comment: Maybe it'd be appropriate to summarise the content from the link here in case it breaks.

Comment: I think to use *be* is far, far stronger than *should*. "He is not to know" means he must not know, not merely that he should not know.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I thought about using *must* when writing my answer. But when should is used with *not/never*, I don't think there is much difference between them, It is different from comparing "must" and "should".