# Passive Voice with ''to be to be and past participle''

Tags: grammaticality

This Association’s standards **are to be used** globally for all ABC related Engineering issues.

My question is that is ''are to be used'' passive structure? And if it is, what type is it. Because I can not see this kind of structure when I check the passive voice chart.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [You ARE not TO be here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/278157/you-are-not-to-be-here). // [Grammaring](https://www.grammaring.com/be-to-infinitive) has a good overview of the [be + to-infinitive] construction, such as 'You are not to use your calculator/s in the exam.' And indeed passivisation gives say 'Calculators are not to be used in the exam' (the covert by-phrase would be 'by candidates', say).

Comment: Thank you very very much. Perfectly understood.